# Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I'm using Facebook Open Graph through WordPress SEO Plugin by Yoast, How do I resolve this issue? On Facebook my website URL is not displaying the description and thumbnail?

> **Extraneous Property**
>
> Objects of this type do not allow properties named 'fb:page_id'.
>
> **Parser Mismatched Metadata**
>
> The parser's result for this metadata did not match the input
>   metadata. Likely, this was caused by the data being ordered in an
>   unexpected way, multiple values being given for a property only
>   expecting a single value, or property values for a given property
>   being mismatched. Here are the input property =>content pairs that
>   were not seen in the parsed result: 'og:locale:locale => en_US,
>   fb:page_id => 2052817970'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the fb:page_id meta tag; it's deprecated [since December](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/608/) - if you see any references to it still in the documentation they're incorrect and need to be updated